# Customizing Fancy Header fancyhdr package for my report

Tags: fancyhdr, texmaker

I am newbie in LATEX and writing a thesis report and I want to add some information about chapter number and its name in header of document.So I am using `fancyhdr` package. I want `fancyhdr` to show **Chapter 1** on left side of header and its name let say **Introduction** on right side of header.Please help how I can be able to do this? Please make sure I don't want this two text Chapter 1 and Introduction in bold.

My code is:

```
% Customising headers - fancyhdr.pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\textsc{\leftmark}}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textsc{\@chapapp}\ \thechapter:\ 
#1}{}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You give no clue about the class in use. You are also redefining the same command twice. That makes your question pretty unclear and hard to answer. I suggest to have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers

Comment: @FaizanZaheer I have updated my answer to help you :)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

So you want to use fancyhdr. As is written in their [`docs`](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/fancyhdr.pdf): Use `\lhead{TEXT}` to write in the left part of the header. Just switch out the `l` if you want it other places: That is `l` is left,`c` is center and `r` is right. Similarly for footer: `\cfoot{TEXT}` would put text at the center footer.

As you are seemingly attempting to do in the code: to obtain the chapter name you can redefine the `\chaptermark` which is set when `\chapter` is called. It is then retrieved (here) with `\leftmark`

The `\@chapapp` contains just the text "Chapter" and `\thechapter` has the chapter number. But you only want it to contain the chapter name, which here is the argument `#1` as called by `\chapter`. Thus your new definition of `\chaptermark` should be:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

Now `\leftmarks` contains the chapter name only.

Like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% Set "Chapter" and chapter _number_ on left header
\lhead{Chapter \thechapter}
% Set chapter _name_ on right side of header
\rhead{\nouppercase{\textsc{\leftmark}}}
% Set what is to be set in \leftmark
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \clearpage
    Some report goes here
\end{document}
```

*Edit*: As @Johannes_B points out: using `\chaptermark` is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Your code is right.But I want Latex to add the chapter number and its title automatically e.g let say I am writing in Chapter 1 named "Introduction" and then I added newpage for writing further then it should display the ongoing chapter number on left side and its name as it is Introduction to right side.How it can be done?

Comment: By chapter, do you mean section? Or are you using the `book` documentclass? I have updated the code to show the current section title.

Comment: If you want to use chapters, you just change, in my code: `\documentclass{article}` -> `\documentclass{book}`, `\leftmark` -> `\rightmark` and `\section`->`\chapter`

Comment: I am using report class and I want Chapter Number and Chapter Title to be shown separated instead of shown combined as "Chapter 1 . Introduction ". I want to split this two one so that I will be able to print on left and right side of header and Latex should do this to all other chapter automatically,because in right mark it store section and in left mark it store chapter title and number information.I want to split this left mark and print half on left side and half on right side of header.

Comment: Updated it to do exactly that. Let me know if this is what you wanted?

Comment: Have you ever heard of marks?

Comment: Only `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`. However, this gives the full text `Chapter 1 . Introduction`, which OP does not want. I couldn't seem to find a cleaner way to obtain only the chapter name. I can do some more research and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Turns out I hadn't really heard of `\marks`, but I have now. Thanks @Johannes_B. Is this answer better?

Comment: I thought more about \chaptermark.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Thank you so much that's what I wanted.

Comment: @FaizanZaheer Glad I could help. Please mark this answer as accepted if you found it satisfactory :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion:

```
\documentclass{report}
% Customising headers - fancyhdr.pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
  {\markboth{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0\@chapapp\ \thechapter\fi\hfill#1}{}}
\makeatother
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

Or with a KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
% Customising headers - fancyhdr.pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chapapp\ \thechapter}{}\hfill#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Unnumbered Chapter}
\Blindtext[10]
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But then it is recommended to use `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
 %Customising headers
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chapapp\ \thechapter\hfill}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Unnumbered Chapter}
\Blindtext[10]
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```